# Getting bash history-complete-backwards/fowards and vi-mode to work with tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, inputrc

I'm using bash on Ubuntu 12.04 my inputrc contains:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on""
```

for my history completion

I also put bash in vi mode with `set -o vi` in my bash_profile.

I've noticed that when I run tmux, if vi mode is on, tmux does not use my inputrc configuration. If I turn vi mode off, it works normally. Is there a way I can have both?

Comment: Unless it's a typo, I think you have unnecessary quote marks with `completion-ignore-case`.

Comment: Yes, they are unnecessary, I think they got left in when I copy pasted those lines from another source. Either way it seems to work.